# Checking User's role in Google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Need to check if the logged in user is a Developer, Owner or Viewer in google appengine in java.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status) explains about putting constraint such that the user have to be Administrator but I did not find any Java API whcih can give me the role .

Answer (score 1):

The [UserService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService) has an `isUserAdmin()` method which gives this information.

Comment: @NeilGhosh note that from App Engine's point of view from your code you cannot distinguish the actual roles that you are putting them in the Dashboard but only if they are on that list.

Comment: Ok, so anyone who is a developer or owner will return true for isUserAdmin() right ? , so that I can restrict the viewers ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible.  The Users service does not distinguish between different roles.

Per the [python docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers) (I can't find this in the java documentaion):

> An administrator is a user who can access the Administration Console for the application.

The api call checks for the presence of 'X-AppEngine-Inbound-User-Is-Admin' in the headers.